# App with C++20 atomic wait/notify: is this an user error

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, stdatomic

I tried to create a test code to check how atomic operations are synchronized. It should test the observation order of `a`...`d` variables from multiple waiting threads with different kinds of memory ordering.

I have one writer thread and multiple reader threads. The synchronization is done by the `cycleCounter` and the `writerReady` atomic variables.

If you prefer to read the code instead of a long explanation [go ahead](https://godbolt.org/z/nP5aMf8Kv).

The logic is the following:

The writer logic:

1. The writer waits to `writerReady` to be reset to `false` (the last reader will reset it to `false`) - At this point we can state that every reader saw and processed the data from the previous cycle and the only thing they can do is waiting right now.
2. The writer sets the `readyReaderMask` to zero, no reader threads saw the new data yet. No race condition as the threads are waiting for the `cycleCounter` to change.
3. Increases the `cycleCounter` and notifies the readers. A race begins (by purpose).
4. Sets `a` and `b` (flips them)
5. Sets `writerReady` and notifies everybody waiting on it
6. Sets `c` and `d` (flips them)

The readers:

1. Wait `cycleCounter` to increase. `cycleCounter` can be increased only by the writer and the writer needs to wait for all of the readers to report ready. It is safe to expect that if it changes from `prevLocalCounter` it must increase exactly by 1 and a new race has begun.
2. Reads `a` and `b`
3. Waits `writerReady` to be set by the writer thread
4. Reads `c` and `d`
5. Logs the data it read
6. With an atomic `fetch_or` to `readyReaderMask` reports itself ready.
7. If the atomic `fetch_or` returned a bitmask that contained all the threads except the current thread ready then the current thread was the last who saw and processed the data, it sets `writerReady` false and notifies the writer thread to start a new race.

I was sure that with `memory_order_seq_cst` memory ordering everything is well defined and sequenced, but noticed that it is not the case.

The application always stops well, so the notifications are always delivered and the `waits` awake. But I cannot explain how the following output could be produced:

```
Thread 5 cycle: 1 A: 1 B: 1 C: 0 D: 0
Thread 5 cycle: 2 A: 1 B: 1 C: 0 D: 0
```

In two consecutive cycles at least `C` and `D` should change because of the reader->writer_flips_the_bools->reader ping-ponging.

MSVC tends to produce more of the faulty outputs than GCC and Clang, but I saw them on every compilers. Most probably I have been trying to find the bug for too long, so it must be a facepalm but I'm kind of stuck.

[The code and the output with GCC, Clang and MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/nP5aMf8Kv)

Pasted here as well:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

static constexpr size_t readerCount = 12;
static constexpr std::memory_order memoryOrderToTest = std::memory_order_seq_cst;

std::atomic<size_t> cycleCounter{0};

std::atomic<bool> a{0};
std::atomic<bool> b{0};
std::atomic<bool> c{0};
std::atomic<bool> d{0};
std::atomic<bool> writerReady{false};
std::atomic<size_t> readyReaderMask{0};
std::mutex logMutex;

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::thread writerThread{[](){
        while(true) {
            // Wait to the last reader to set writerReady to false
            writerReady.wait(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            // Zero out the ready reader count
            readyReaderMask.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            // Add one to the cycleCounter and notify the readers
            const size_t localCycleCounter{cycleCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst)};
            cycleCounter.notify_all();

            // Exit after 10 cycles
            if(localCycleCounter == 10) {
                break;
            }

            const bool odd{localCycleCounter % 2 != 0};

            // The race begins

            a.store(odd, memoryOrderToTest);
            b.store(odd, memoryOrderToTest);
            writerReady.store(true, memoryOrderToTest);
            writerReady.notify_all();
            c.store(odd, memoryOrderToTest);
            d.store(odd, memoryOrderToTest);
        };
    }};

    std::vector<std::thread> readerThreeads;
    readerThreeads.reserve(readerCount);

    for(size_t readerIndex = 0; readerIndex < readerCount; ++readerIndex) {
        readerThreeads.emplace_back([readerIndex](){
            size_t prevLocalCounter{0};
            std::stringstream log{};

            do {
                // Wait for the writer to start a new cycle
                cycleCounter.wait(prevLocalCounter, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

                const bool localA = a.load(memoryOrderToTest);
                const bool localB = b.load(memoryOrderToTest);
                writerReady.wait(false, memoryOrderToTest);
                const bool localC = c.load(memoryOrderToTest);
                const bool localD = d.load(memoryOrderToTest);

                log << "Thread " << readerIndex << " cycle: " << prevLocalCounter << " A: " << localA << " B: " << localB << " C: " << localC << " D: " << localD << "\n";

                prevLocalCounter = cycleCounter.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
                //++prevLocalCounter; // Should be equivalent as we know that each reader should run once for each write

                size_t prevReadyMask{readyReaderMask.fetch_or(1 << readerIndex, std::memory_order_seq_cst)};
                if((prevReadyMask & (1 << readerIndex)) != 0) {
                    logMutex.lock();
                    std::cerr << "Critical: Reader #" << readerIndex << " reported ready twice." << std::endl;
                    logMutex.unlock();
                    exit(-1);
                }
                prevReadyMask |= (1 << readerIndex);
                if(prevReadyMask == ((1 << readerCount) - 1)) {
                    writerReady.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
                    writerReady.notify_all();
                }
            } while(prevLocalCounter < 10);

            logMutex.lock();
            std::cout << log.rdbuf() << std::endl;
            logMutex.unlock();
        });
    }

    writerThread.join();
    for(std::thread& currReader: readerThreeads) {
        currReader.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code directly in the question.

Comment: When the writer wakes up the readers, it hasn't set `c` and `d` yet. There is a race on whether the loads in the reader will happen first or the writes in the writer will happen first. To clarify, I mean waking up on `writerReady`, not on `cycleCounter`.

Comment: Also, are you sure the whole `prevReadyMask`-related trickery works as expected? Why not use `std::barrier` or `counting_semaphore` there?

Comment: @user17732522 The whole experiment is about that race, so I would like to have that particular one :) `a` and `b` are always set before the notification, so at least those ones should alternate. But those are not part of the synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @Broothy Then I think "_In two consecutive cycles at least C and D should change_" meant to be "A and B"?

Comment: @alagner Good point, you are completely right. However I'm sure it works, if it didn't then the execution would never be continued.

Comment: But anyway the other way around has the same problem. The writer may write to A and B before the reader starts waiting and before it reads them or it may write to them after the reader started waiting and therefore after it read them.

Comment: @user17732522 OMG, I think you are right. Let me think a bit, but I think it is the issue.

Comment: You can remove all the `readyReaderMask` stuff from the question code btw. It happens with a single reader as well. Basically, the wait on `writerReady` in the reader doesn't do anything useful. It assures that `A` and `B` have been set when it unblocks, but at that point you already don't care about them anymore.

Comment: @user17732522 I added that part to ensure each reader thread reports itself only one ready. In the original implementation it was a simple counter.

Comment: @user17732522 It was the issue indeed, please answer it for the credit :)